# fail to load subview to storyboard using .xib file

Tags: ios, subview

Recently I am studying the book "iOS 12 Programming Fundamentals with Swift". Under the section "manual Nib Loading", readers are supposed to be able to load a nib using .xib file. I followed the three steps: load the nib (which is the .xib file), obtain the instances that it creates as it loads, and do something with those instances. But I cannot see the designed view shown in the running app's interface. Any possibility why this is so?

p.s. The name of the .xib file is View.xib.

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let arr = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("View", owner: nil)!
    let v = arr[0] as! UIView
    self.view.addSubview(v)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why I failed to load the .xib file. In Main.storyboard, under the Custom Class in the Identity Inspector, I should set the Class value as the name of the .swift file which is used to instantiate the view controller, "ViewController", instead of the default value "UIViewController".

Answer (score 0):

try

```
let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("View", owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
self.view.addSubview(view);
```